# Archer T4UH not recognised - 17.10

Tags: wireless, 17.10, realtek-wireless

Recently installed Ubuntu alongside windows 7 as I plan to replace windows with Ubuntu later on, but my wireless adapter has no Kernel support, and the rtl8192 package everyone says to use does not work in 17.10

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: It is the AC1300 V2 model

EDIT 2: lsusb result from terminal:

`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 2357:010e

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1b1c:1b0a Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: lsusb

Comment: Done the command, result is now on the question

Answer (score 1):

Your device is actually driven by the driver *8812au*. There is a package in the Ubuntu repositories called *rtl8812au-dkms*, however, it does not cover your exact 2357:010e device. 0101 and 010d and several other similar devices are covered. We will, emboldened by this post, modify the code: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345375/issue-while-installing-driver-for-archer-t4u-ac1300-on-mint-17

> I can confirm the above solution worked for me:  The only
>   difference I had to do was when I ran the command 'lsusb'. It showed a
>   device named '2357:010e'. When I had to add a new 'line in usb_intf.c'
>   I had to change the reference from 'd' to 'e' instead. :)

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
cd rtl8812au/os_dep/linux
nano usb_intf.c
```

Scroll down until you find the line that says:

```
{USB_DEVICE(0x2357, 0x010d),.driver_info = RTL8812}, /* TP-Link - Archer T4U, AC1300 */
```

Simply change the d to an e so that is now reads:

```
{USB_DEVICE(0x2357, 0x010e),.driver_info = RTL8812}, /* TP-Link - Archer T4U, AC1300 */
```

Spacing, punctuation and spelling are critical so proofread carefully, twice. Write out the file (Ctrl+o) and exit (Ctrl+x).

Now do:

```
cd ~/rtl8812au
make
sudo make install
```

This 'makes' on my 17.10 system with a very few possibly harmless errors. Next do:

```
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Is your wireless working? Please report back as I will have another step if we are successful.

Comment: It did not work, ubuntu still says it can't be found.

Comment: What didn't work? It didn't compile correctly? It didn't install? The module didn't load? Errors? Warnings?? Where does it say, "...it can't be found"? Did you try a reboot?

Comment: No errors displayed, I rebooted and plugged in the adapter and it was not detected at all

Comment: What does the terminal command: `iwconfig` report? How about: `dmesg | grep rtl` Also: `modinfo 8812au | grep 010E`

Comment: iwconfig reports `no wireless extensions`, dmesg reports this:  `https://pastebin.com/7aaY0rZN` and modinfo returns nothing.

Comment: If the modinfo returns nothing, then your usb_intf.c step was not done correctly. Please retrace each step carefully and, before 'make' do 'make clean.'

Comment: I followed your steps, and it still isn't showing anything.

Comment: How about: `modinfo 8812au | grep 010E` ? It should show: alias:          usb:v2357p010Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*  Does it? If not, the `usb_intf.c` step is still incorrect.